# How can I filter a PHP string to only display a unique result?

Tags: php, loops, csv, foreach

I have a CSV file that I am outputting to a table via PHP. The CSV data appears like this:

```
0072534,800:fixed:9.9900:0072534|6500:fixed:9.9900:0072538|2100:fixed:9.9900:0072537
0072538,800:fixed:9.9900:0072534|6500:fixed:9.9900:0072538|2100:fixed:9.9900:0072537
0072537,800:fixed:9.9900:0072534|6500:fixed:9.9900:0072538|2100:fixed:9.9900:0072537
```

I am struggling to work out how I can get the second CSV column to only display the data relevant to the ID in the first CSV column. The desired result would be:

```
0072534, 800
0072538, 6500
0072537, 2100
```

(The first part of the second column is the data I am after, i.e. the the data before the first ':' )

Does that make sense and can someone suggest a solution? Thank you!!

Comment: I am bit seeing any relation between 0072538 and 6500

Comment: The values you're specifying in relation to what you requested seem to be two different things. Could you provide more clarity?

Comment: [productcode], [optionvalue]:[optiontype]:[optionprice]:[optionproductcode]

To give you some background, column one is a product code, and column two is all the custom options for the group of products that that product belongs to. So in this example, the product is available in 3 sizes, 800, 6500 and 2100. The product code is at the end of the custom option, and each option is seperated by '|' .

Comment: I am trying to get the option value that is linked to ONLY that product code in row one

Comment: I believe I interpreted your question and gave you the correct answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each row (however you're parsing your CSV file), and further iterate over each CSV column - exploding the second column.

This is assuming that you want to get the beginning value after each `|` character, dependent on the row number. If I am misunderstanding, let me know - your question could be far clearer.

For example, something like this:

```
$count = 0;

$final = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {

$columns = explode(",", $row);

$column2 = explode("|", $columns[1]);


$length = strpos($column2[$count], ':');
$column2 = substr($column2[$count], 0, $length);

$final[] = array($columns[0], $column2);

$count++;
}
```

Comment: I apologise for not being clearer, I struggled to explain it.

$f = fopen("children01.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {

foreach ($line as $index => $cell) {

if (strpos($cell,':00') !== false) {

// CODE HERE

}
}

Comment: That is how I am tackling it at the moment, using an IF statement to check that the cell is a product option, as there are lots of other columns

Comment: Almost there - I am trying to explode the string, search the array, and only display the array key that contains a result (if it has a result). The following code doesn't work - what am I doing wrong?

    $cell0 = explode('|', $cell);
    $search = array_search($sku, $cell0);
    $cell = $cell0[$search];